# phpMyAdmin error in DatabaseInterface.class.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

When I develop my website in offline mode, go to the MySQL Admin section of InstantWordpress, and log in with "root" user and blank password, I can't see my website's database tree on the left and I get the following error message:

```
Notice in .\libraries\DatabaseInterface.class.php#2295
Undefined offset: 1

Backtrace:
.\libraries\server_common.inc.php#37: PMA_DatabaseInterface->isUserType(string 'create')
.\index.php#110: include(.\libraries\server_common.inc.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=6294&title=phpMyAdmin_Notice_in_./libraries/Header.class.php .

The site notes that it is just a notice - which can be disabled.

Comment the following line:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Actually I just can find the following line in two php.ini files located in iwpserver\server and iwpserver\server\config_tpl : error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: What's more is that once I click on any link of the GUI, it makes me log out and I have this warning message: Warning in .\libraries\session.inc.php#126
session_regenerate_id() [<a href='function.session-regenerate-id'>function.session-regenerate-id</a>]: Session object destruction failed

Backtrace

.\libraries\session.inc.php#126: session_regenerate_id(boolean true)
.\libraries\common.inc.php#871: PMA_secureSession()
.\db_structure.php#12: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Comment out the line found and see if it resolves - If not, then uncomment again.

Comment: phpMyAdmin Version : 4.4.13.1. I commented it but it didn't resolved anything